# What is the best way to deploy a tensorflow trained graph into production?

Tags: python-3.x, c++11, tensorflow, cntk

I have been working on machine learning problems lately as part of my internship. So far I have been using Tensorflow with python because that's what I am most comfortable with. Once a problem is solved using deep learning, I am left with the architecture of the network and the weights. Now, my problem is, how can I deploy my solution in production? I won't be using tensorflow serving because it is mainly for huge applications where you set a remote server and your developed application will make requests to this server. In my case, I just want to develop a machine learning solution and integrate it into an already existing software that uses C++ with visual studio 2017.

So far and after a lot of research, I have some solutions in mind :

1) Using the "dnn" module from OpenCV : this module can load graphs and you can do inference and other operations (like extracting a specific layer from the network at run time). This module seemed very promising but then I started facing some problems when using networks that are a little bit different from the one used in the example described in OpenCV github, they used "inception5h" for the example and when I tried to load "inception_v3" there was an error about some unknown layer in the network, namely the JPEG_decode layer.

2) Building tensorflow from source and using it directly with C++. This solution seemed like the best one but then I encountered so many problems with parts of my code not compiling while others do. I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Windows 10. So although I was able to build tensorflow from source, I wasn't able to compile all parts of my code, in fact it wasn't even my code, it was an example from tensorflow website, this one : [tensorflow C++ example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/cc/guide).

3) Another possibility that I am entertaining is using tensorflow for designing the solution and then using another machine learning framework such as Caffe2, CNTK...etc for deployment into production. I have found some possibilities to convert graphs from one framework to another here : [models converters](https://github.com/ysh329/deep-learning-model-convertor). I thought that this could be a reasonable solution because all I have to do is find the framework most compatible with windows and just do a model conversion once I finish designing my solution in tensorflow and python. The conversion process though seems a little too good, am I wrong?

4) A final possibility that I am thinking of is using CPython. So basically, I will create my the pipeline for prediction in python, wrap in some python functions then use `<Python.h>` in my Visual Studio project and make calls to those functions using C++, here's an example : [embedding python in C++](https://docs.python.org/3.1/extending/embedding.html). I have never used a solution like this before and I am not sure about all the things that could go wrong.

So basically, what do you think is the best solution to deploy a machine learning solution into an already existing project on Visual Studio that uses C++? Am I missing a better solution? Any guidelines or hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: so which framework did you use ?

Comment: I just added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using solution 2. After the new updates from tensorflow, it's now easier to build tensorflow from source on Windows. With this solution, I didn't need to worry about the compatibility of my models since I use tensorflow with python for prototyping and I use it with C++ for production.

[EDIT] : In 2021, I am now using ONNX Runtime (ORT) for deploying my models in production as part of a C++ application. The documentation for ORT is not great but the tool itself is very good.

Comment: On one hand this is encouraging - it may provide an answer for my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61812992/how-to-integrate-tensorflow-keras-model-into-windows-application-for-fast-infe). On the other hand... it took >18 months between you asking the question and finding an answer. This suggests it is still a terrible idea to try to use Tensorflow natively inside Windows C++ applications :-( Do you have any updated opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I used CNTK from the beginning because I just wanted to stay in my C++ world in Visual Studio, and knew that I wanted to deploy as part of my C++ desktop App.  No Tensorflow, no Python, no cloud, not even .NET, and no translating models.  Just do it in CNTK from the start.  I have a commercial product now using Deep Learning.  Cool!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My only concern is that tensorflow is well documented and there are many tools that were developed by the community and that use tensorflow (such as tensorflow object detection API). Do you think it will be easy to develop those tools using CNTK? I just feel that it will be a time waster, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider exporting your NN model (which is not restricted to tensorflow) using ONNX to Intel Vino or TensorRT in order to export your model to C++ for optimized CPU or optimized GPU

It's states [here](https://hackernoon.com/optimizing-neural-networks-for-production-with-intels-openvino-a7ee3a6883d) that Intel Vino is twice as fast as tensorflow

Comment: Now I am actually using ONNX Runtime without the need for VINO backend or TensorRT.